# Validation cleaner regex for ssn

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I wrote a jquery validate class to invalidate all ssn's with all one digit except for solid zeros which for us is valid.  However I feel the regex is pretty messy. I was wondering if anyone knew a "cleaner way" to write this.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ssnFABSValidation", function(ssn) {
    ssn = ssn.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    ssn = ssn.replace(/[_]+/g, "");
   if (ssn.match(/^([1-9])\1\1[-]\1\1[-]\1\1\1\1/)||(ssn.length<11)){
        return false
    }
    return true;
}, "Please specify a valid SSN or use 000-00-0000 for unknown SSN");
```

Comment: what about `/[1-9]{3}-[1-9]{2}-[1-9]{4}/`? Clean enuff? or `/([1-9])\1{2}[-]\1{2}[-]\1{3}/` if you like.

Comment: @Christoph the \1's are checking against the previous value to make sure they are not repeating. the format in general could be done easier with your method, however repeating digits would not be caught.

Comment: also SSN have several restrictions, don't you need to implement these - e.g. `666-...` or `987-65-432[0-9]` ?